# Why do I get this error= [line: 33] Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method reverse() from the type Reverse1

Tags: java

Line 33 is where I get the error and I'm not sure why....can someone please help me. Line 33 is the one that says **reverse()**. And public String reverse is the method in the class

```
public String reverse() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter anything in here make sure it is a letter or number..anything else will be destroyed");
    String a = scan.nextLine();
    String reverse = "";
    for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + a.charAt(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Here is your input in reverse: ");
    return reverse;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    reverse();
}
```

Comment: You call non static method reverse from static method.

Comment: Make reverse method as static - public static String reverse()

Comment: You can't call non static methods from static methods. So, you have two options: 1) add static keyword in reverse() method 2) Put reverse() inside a class that can be instanciated, so you can call new Reverse() and after call the method.